# Jet.OLEDB or ACE.OLEDB MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm using excel vba to pull data from a MS Access DB - this is using Excel 2013 and Access 2013 32bit. The code historically has used:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
```

However some computers have upgraded to Excel 2016 64bit and the Jet provider is not available for 64bit. I have changed the code to:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
```

which works for both 64bit and 32bit systems. However, I have noticed a significant speed drop in loading/saving data just from changing this line. Does anyone know why this can be and how I can improve it?

Comment: This entirely depends on what code is doing. I cannot imagine or have experienced such a speed drop. Consider editing your question with specifics as this is too broad.

Comment: I'm presuming that the computers that are upgraded to 2016 Excel are also upgraded to Access 2016 64 bit?

Comment: @zac yes it is also

Comment: @Parfait the code is genuinely just inserting a row onto an access database and then calling back a query into the access DB

Comment: *a query* can be anything. Please post example!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in having to choose the ACE provider for x64 bits.

And the big advantage of JET was it was (and still is) installed on all copies of windows by default. So no need to install Access or the runtime, or previous the office connectivity package.

As for performance? There has been a few comments about performance in regards to ACE x64.

However, one trick or suggestion is to ensure that the connection stays open. In other words, are you sure the row processing is going slow, or it is the overall time?

(perhaps put a test msg box, or test in your code.

Eg:

```
 Dim T    as single

 T = timer()

 ‘ your code here

 Debug.print timer() – t
```

The above will thus spit out the time to the debug window (while in VBA ide hit ctrl-g to display the immediate/debug window.

The reason why I suggest force open idea is often you find that ACE takes a VERY long time to open. But once open then the data reading has good performance (same as before).

So, I suggest to check and try this fix.

So open a table (any table) and KEEP it open. Now run your existing code (that may well open + close other tables). The issue is when ACE attempts to open a table, it tries to put locks on the mdb/accdb file and it is this process that takes VERY VERY long time.

However, if you force (keep) open one table, then this VERY slow process of ACE attempting to lock the file for read/write does not occur each time you execute a query, or create additional recordsets in code.

So, if the row reading speed is fast, but the time to START + open is very slow, then before you run + test your routines, force open a table to some reocrdset (keep it active and in scope), and THEN try your code.

I find 9 out of 10 times, this results in elimination of this slow speed, and often I seen the results are nothing short of spectacular (it will run faster then before!!!)